# MongoDB 'count()' is very slow. How do we refine/work around with it?

Tags: performance, mongodb, count

I am currently using MongoDB with millions of data records. I discovered one thing that's pretty annoying.

When I use 'count()' function with a small number of queried data collection, it's very fast. However, when the queried data collection contains thousand or even millions of data records, the entire system becomes very slow.

I made sure that I have indexed the required fields.

Has anybody encountered an identical thing? How do you do to improve that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is now another optimization than create proper index.

```
db.users.ensureIndex({name:1});
db.users.find({name:"Andrei"}).count();
```

If you need some counters i suggest to precalculate them whenever it possible. By using atomic [$inc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$inc) operation and not use `count({})` at all.

But mongodb guys working hard on mongodb, so, `count({})` improvements they are planning in mongodb 2.1 according to jira [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752).

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, let's say that I would like to filter out data records and count the record number. In this case, $inc does not help me a lot, does it?

Comment: @WinstonChen: It depends on your filter. Provide an example i will answer.

Comment: Thank you. Let's say that I have millions of records like this:{_id:"hash_code_here", bookname:"The Four Steps to the Epiphany", authoer:"Steven-Gary-Blank", category:10}. I have 1 million books or so whose category is 10, and the same as category 9, 8, 7, etc. I have page with a paging feature that filters out and shows my visitors all the books with category 10, or 9, or 8, or 7.... The category is supposed to be one of the criteria in the filter. Visitors are also able to add in "author" criteria or some other criteria. How could I implement it with $inc?

Comment: Please note that `ensureIndex` was deprecated since 3.0. Use `createIndex` instead.

Answer (score 10):

You can ensure that the index is really used without any disk access.

Let's say you want to count records with name : "Andrei"

You ensure index on name (as you've done)
and

```
db.users.find({name:"andrei"}, {_id:0, name:1}).count()
```

you can check that it is the fastest way to count (except with precomputing) by checking if

```
db.users.find({name:"andrei"}, {_id:0, name:1}).explain()
```

displays a index_only field set to true.

This trick will ensure that your query will retrieve records only from ram (index) and not from disk.

Comment: If MongoDB decides that it should _not_ do `index_only` for an operation like `count`, by default, then that's sounds pretty much like a bug to me.

Comment: it was true in 2011, maybe this has changed with https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752

Answer (score 8):

You are pretty much out of luck for now, count in mongodb is awful and won't be getting better in the near future. See: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752

From experience, you should pretty much never use it unless it's a one time thing, something that occurs very rarely, or your database is pretty small.

As @Andrew Orsich stated, use counters whenever possible (the downfall to counters is the global write lock, but better than count() regardless).

Answer (score 7):

For me the solution was change index to **sparse**.
It depend on specific situation, just give it a try if you can.

```
db.Account.createIndex( { "date_checked_1": 1 }, { sparse: true } )

db.Account.find({    
     "dateChecked" : { $exists : true }    
}).count()
```

318 thousands records in collection

- 0.31 sec - with sparse index
- 0.79 sec - with non-sparse index

Answer (score 4):

Adding my observations based on latest version of mongodb 4.4. I have `0.80 TB` collection size.

I have created an index (`UserObject.CountryID`) for my collection. and ran this query.

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
    $match : {
        "UserObject.CountryID" : 3
    }
}]).group({_id: "Count", count: {$sum: 1}})
```

It took total

- 06800 ms to fetch count of around 13 million (1.3 crore) records searching `0.80 TB` collection size.
- 16274 ms to fetch count of around 35 million (3.5 crore) records searching `0.80 TB` collection size.
- 41615 ms to fetch count of around 42 million (4.2 crore) records searching `0.80 TB` collection size.

[image]

[image]

[image]