# caching db.collection.count() mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a website where people vote and upload on images- and on the homepage I want to display the number of uploads. So I start off with this:

```
db.uploads.count( { active: true }
```

But I've read that becomes slow once many documents are added to my collection. So my thought was to create a new collection `stats` which has (single?) document. Every time an image is uploaded I can run a `$inc` on a `uploadCount` field... effectively caching my query. I could then query this document for my website.

So my question, is this an acceptable approach? Are there any best practices here or better ideas?

I found the `$inc` idea here: [MongoDB 'count()' is very slow. How do we refine/work around with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658228/mongodb-count-is-very-slow-how-do-we-refine-work-around-with-it) but its from 2011 so I'm unsure if this is still a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some validity to what is mentioned in that post in that the general premise is that what you would be doing in retrieval is going to be a faster operation than any index or collection scan that may take place. And to the point where maintaining an *incremental count* of the documents in a collection is something that you can live with.

That said, as mentioned in the answer to that question, there *was* at the time an open [JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752) that has long since been addressed and closed. So suffice to say, the performance issues that people were experiencing have long since been addressed, and **count()** returns faster than in previous versions.

So getting counts from *query* results where you may *filter* will respond better and will generally be necessary for those kinds of operations. But if you **are** prepared to live with *"keeping your own counters"*, and you *beleive* the performance benefits to be substantial enough for your circumstances, then the approach you suggest will be certainly valid for you.