# What's the right way to check if collection.find success in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

The [Meteor document](http://docs.meteor.com/#find) said 'find returns a cursor', and can use 'fetch' to return all matching documents, but I didn't find a complete reference of this 'cursor' object.

I want to use this 'cursor' object to check if find sucessfully got some result or got nothing.

Following is what I am doing now:

```
if (Tags.find({name: tag["tag"]}).fetch().length === 0) {
   // Not found, add default documents 
}
```

Not sure if this is right way(best practice) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom is to use [.findOne](http://docs.meteor.com/#findone):

```
if (!Tags.findOne(...)) {
  // nothing found, add default documents
}
```

This is more efficient than `fetch()` because it only queries the database for one document.

You can also use [`<cursor>.count`](http://docs.meteor.com/#count), but beware that in [Mongo, count operations are expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658228/mongodb-count-is-very-slow-how-do-we-refine-work-around-with-it).