# count slow in mongodb 2.6.8

Tags: mongodb, count

I've a **find** request which takes 0.031sec, but when I try to do the same request with a count, it takes over 1sec.

I tried different indexes but it's always the same problem.
Count is still slow.

any idea?

**volume**
1600000 documents

**My request**

```
db.books.find(
{
    "categories" : { $eq : null},
    "theme" : "comics"
}
)
```

**My Index**

```
{
    "categories" : 1,
    "theme" : 1

}
```

**Explain**

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor categories_1_theme_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 353912,
    "nscannedObjects" : 353912,
    "nscanned" : 353912,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 354821,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 354821,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 2771,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 1111,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "theme" : [
            [
                "comics",
                "comics"
            ]
        ],
        "categories" : [
            [
                null,
                null
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "xxxmongoxxx:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "works" : 353913,
        "yields" : 2771,
        "unyields" : 2771,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 353912,
        "needTime" : 0,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "children" : [
            {
                "type" : "FETCH",
                "works" : 353913,
                "yields" : 2771,
                "unyields" : 2771,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 353912,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 353912,
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "IXSCAN",
                        "works" : 353913,
                        "yields" : 2771,
                        "unyields" : 2771,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 353912,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "keyPattern" : "{ categories: 1, theme: 1 }",
                        "isMultiKey" : 0,
                        "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['categories']: [\"comics\", \"comics\"], field #1['theme']: [null, null]",
                        "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                        "matchTested" : 0,
                        "keysExamined" : 353912,
                        "children" : []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658228/mongodb-count-is-very-slow-how-do-we-refine-work-around-with-it

Comment: Hello,thanks for answer, but I've already read this thread. The issue seems to be fixed in 2.3.2 jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1752 but I use mongo 2.6.8

Comment: I've tried my request on mongo 2.4.9 with the same data, same indexes. The count takes 0.6 sec ! there is a regression in mongo 2.6.8 ?

Comment: Hi, it seems that my server is not in good health. I install mongodb 2.6.8 in local and do a mongorestore on the server. The count request is not slow and responds in the same duration of mongodb 2.4.9