# MongoDB: count is slow when using $in

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

MongoDB 3.0.3

These two lines finish in less than a second

```
db.documents.count({'docType': 'fcsNotificationEF'});
db.documents.count({'docType': 'fcsNotificationZK'});
```

And this one didn't finish in a minute

```
db.documents.count({'docType': {$in: ['fcsNotificationEF', 'fcsNotificationZK']}})
```

I have an index for `docType`. As I understand, this line from `db.currentOp` output confirms that index is used:

```
"planSummary": "IXSCAN { docType: 1.0 }"
```

This [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7658467/1085375) didn't finish in a minute as well.

Comment: The query in question is for find, whereas the above two queries are for count. How long does `db.documents.count({'docType': {$in: ['fcsNotificationEF', 'fcsNotificationZK']}})` take?

Comment: thanks for noticing the mistake! see the edit (I re-checked and yes, `count` with `$in` isn't to finish any time soon, just like `find`).

Comment: I ran into exactly same problem as yours. 2017 and it seems it's still not solved.