# Mongodb array object count by value

Tags: mongodb

I have json with the following structure

```
db.testCollection.insert(
{
  "m_id": 2,
  "sys_data":[
    {"sattr": 
      {
        "size": 2,
        "d_data":
        [
          {"d_counter": 2,
          "client_ip":"1.1.1.1",
          "d_date":"02/01/01"}
          {"d_counter": 2,
          "client_ip":"1.1.1.1",
          "d_date":"02/01/01"}
          {"d_counter": 2,
          "client_ip":"1.1.1.1",
          "d_date":"03/01/01"}
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

db.testCollection.insert(
{
  "m_id": 2,
  "sys_data":[
    {"sattr": 
      {
        "size": 2,
        "d_data":
        [
          {"d_counter": 2,
          "client_ip":"1.1.1.1",
          "d_date":"02/01/01"}
       ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the count where d_date ='02/01/01', So the output for above json is 3. (two from first json and one from the second)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the count. This allows you to **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** the deeply nested embedded documents (with the help of the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)**), filter out the unwanted documents using the **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator which is similar to the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)** query and use the **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** accumulator operator in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline to determine the count of the matching documents.

Something like this:

**Populate test collection:**

```
db.testCollection.insert([
{        
    "m_id" : 2,
    "sys_data" : [ 
        {
            "sattr" : {
                "size" : 2,
                "d_data" : [ 
                    {
                        "d_counter" : 2,
                        "client_ip" : "1.1.1.1",
                        "d_date" : "02/01/01"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "d_counter" : 2,
                        "client_ip" : "1.1.1.1",
                        "d_date" : "02/01/01"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "d_counter" : 2,
                        "client_ip" : "1.1.1.1",
                        "d_date" : "03/01/01"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "m_id" : 2,
    "sys_data" : [ 
        {
            "sattr" : {
                "size" : 2,
                "d_data" : [ 
                    {
                        "d_counter" : 2,
                        "client_ip" : "1.1.1.1",
                        "d_date" : "02/01/01"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}])
```

**Run the aggregation pipeline:**

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "sys_data.sattr.d_data.d_date" : "02/01/01"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$sys_data"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$sys_data.sattr.d_data"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "sys_data.sattr.d_data.d_date" : "02/01/01"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
];
db.testCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Sample output:**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "count" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [docs from mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

```
db.testCollection.count( { d_date : "02/01/01"  } )
```

Also, the above is equivalent to:

```
db.testCollection.find( { d_date: "02/01/01" } ).count()
```

If you feel slow performance check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7658228/3809894).