# mongodb count vs find with count

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am performing a count of documents in a mongo (versions 2.4 and 3.2) collection.  The collection is very big, 3821085 documents.  I need to count all documents with a reference `_id`.  I have tried two different queries:

`db.SampleCollection.find({"field._id" : ObjectId("UUID")}).count()`
`db.SampleCollection.count({"field._id" : ObjectId("UUID")})`

This query takes a very long time.  So much time that I have not let it complete, more than 5 minutes and I get scared and kill it.

For this collection `field._id` is not an index.  I do not have relevant info to use an index with this query.

Is there a better approach to count document in mongo.

**UPDATE**:

I understand that I need an index on the field `field._id`.  If I did have an index for the field which approach would perform better on a large collection `db.SampleCollection.find(...).count()` or `db.SampleCollection.count(...)`?  Or is there no difference between the two?

Comment: If you don't have an index on "field._idx" that means that both these queries have to do a full collection scan and it's going to take a while.

Comment: @soundslikeodd i updated the Answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your scenario, you should have an index.

[Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

*Indexes support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. Without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match the query statement.*

**UPDATE:**

the question asked now is different.
Is `collection.find({}).count()` more fast then `collection.count()`?

According to the MongoDB documentation:

[db.collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

*count() is equivalent to the db.collection.find(query).count() construct.*

Comment: sounds like that means if we don't have indexes and you want to do a count, you should cut down the query to an _id field.

Comment: If you just want to count number of Employers inside a collection then is a pretty easy job with ".find().count()" supposing each document is an Employer and you don't need a index. But if you want to count "number of Employers that are >31 years old then your "age" field should have an index in order to avoid a full collection scan.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an index on `field._id` like this:

```
db.SampleCollection.createIndex( { "field._id": 1 } );
```

Then all the queries trying to find/count documents by that field will use this index and will perform faster. For example:

```
db.SampleCollection.count({"field._id" : ObjectId("UUID")});
```

See - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/ and [MongoDB 'count()' is very slow. How do we refine/work around with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658228/mongodb-count-is-very-slow-how-do-we-refine-work-around-with-it)