# Mongodb slow count query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection containing 2 million records like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2bcdde0fab483921eeda9b"),
    "body" : "a big text is here ///",
    "txt_filename" : "/home/ehsan/data/pubmed_data/txt_data/Nutr_Res/Nutr_Res_2013_Mar_33(3)_188-194.txt",
    "processed" : true,
    "xml_filename" : "",
    "type" : "comm"
}
```

When I want to execute this command:

```
db.articles.count({processed: true})
```

it took couple of minutes to see the results. What's the reason? Do I need to put an index on the table? I can query this in Elasticsearch in just a few milliseconds. What's the problem with MongoDB?

Comment: Elasticsearch and mongodb are not comparable. If you want to speed up your query then creating an index on `processed` would definitely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create indexes on fields (*processed*) inorder to get the faster result.

create index:

```
db.articles.createIndex( { "processed": 1 } );
```

You can refer below link for more info.
[mongodb count vs find with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061221/mongodb-count-vs-find-with-count)